# How does one extract the alpha channel from an image using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How does one export just an alpha mask from a PNG using Pillow?

Ideally, the result would be a grayscale image that represents the alpha channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# Open the image and convert it to RGBA, just in case it was indexed
image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGBA')

# Extract just the alpha channel
alpha = image.split()[-1]

# Unfortunately the alpha channel is still treated as such and can't be dumped
# as-is

# Create a new image with an opaque black background
bg = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, (0,0,0,255))

# Copy the alpha channel to the new image using itself as the mask
bg.paste(alpha, mask=alpha)

# Since the bg image started as RGBA, we can save some space by converting it
# to grayscale ('L') Optionally, we can convert the image to be indexed which
# saves some more space ('P') In my experience, converting directly to 'P'
# produces both the Gray channel and an Alpha channel when viewed in GIMP,
# althogh the file sizes is about the same
bg.convert('L').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=8).save(
                                                                mask_path,
                                                                optimize=True)
```

Comment: you are missing a parentesis on `bg = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, (0,0,0,255)` other than that whits worked great

Comment: For me this produces incorrect results if I use this mask later in SVG. It happens because of differences in the interpretation of alpha and colors. Gamma correction certainly is always applied to colors but should it be applied to alpha? Following produces correct result if you are going to use this mask in SVG: `bg = Image.new("L", img.size)` and then `bg.paste(alpha)`

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one channel, there's a newer, more efficient method for this: image[.getchannel()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getchannel)

This also returns a new image, of mode "L", which cuts down on several extra steps for saving.

For example:

```
image = Image.open( inputImagePath ).convert( 'RGBA' )
alphaChannelImage = image.getchannel( 'A' ) # Mode 'L'

# If you want a paletted image to save space (optional line)
alphaChannelImage.convert( 'P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE )

alphaChannelImage.save( outputImagePath )
```